# SQL Server BULK Insert with non standard NULL value

Tags: sql-server

I have a large CSV file with columns that support NULL but the value for NULL is "NA".
How can I import this to SQL server without replacing those values with NULL?

Comment: "without replacing those values with NULL?" = keep NA. Is this what you really mean?

Answer (score 2):

Import it as the string `NA`. It isn't NULL. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

If the field is a *char then why not import the value as NA, and then run a bulk update setting the field to NULL after import?